# WebSocket Connection for xmpp

Tags: java, websocket, xmpp

I am trying to establish a `websocket` connection with `port:5280`,but unable to connect(server is not listening).

```
public static WebSocketClient cc;

public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException 
{
    cc=new WebSocketClient(new URI("ws://localhost:5280")) 
    {

        @Override
        public void onOpen(ServerHandshake arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("onOpen" +arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("onMessage");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("onError");
        }

        @Override
        public void onClose(int arg0, String arg1, boolean arg2)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("onClose");

        }
    };
    cc.connect();
```

Above one is working with new URI(`"ws://localhost:8887/8080/5120"`) but having some problem with port `no-5280`.
Give me any Fix??

Comment: check whether the port is opened in your host ...

Comment: Can you suggest me,how to check?

Comment: are you using windows machine ?

Comment: if you are using windws in you cmd  type netstat -a -n -o and see if your port is listed..

Comment: I Checked using cmd "netstat -an | grep 5280 | grep -i listen                             Output:tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5280            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN